# How to find sum of elements of a list, within a list of strings and numbers Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, sum

```
list1 = [['hello',3],['bye',4].....]
```

I need to find just the sum of the numbers, 3 + 4 = 7 in this case, for an undefined number of item in the list all structured like this

I don't know how to call a spisific element from the sublists from every sublist for a sum command. I have tryed the following but what do I put in the first brackets? Or is there a better way to write this?

```
sum(list1[][1])
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum, tutorial or code writing service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.  You should spend some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer and you may even start to get ideas for solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple two dimensional list, you can try this:

```
list1 = [['hello',3],['bye',4]]
the_sum = sum(i[-1] for i in list1)
```

However, for a list of `n` dimensions, recursion is best:

```
list1 = [['hello',3],['bye',4], [["hi", 19], ["yes", 18]]]

def flatten(s):
   if not isinstance(s, list):
       yield s
   else:
       for i in s:
          for b in flatten(i):
              yield b

final_result = sum(filter(lambda x:isinstance(x, int), list(flatten(list1))))
```

Output:

```
44
```